# Returning an iterator for the end of the doubly linked list with one element

Tags: c++, list, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to implement a doubly linked list and in there I have a end() function which returns an iterator that points to the end of the list.

if I return

```
tail -> next
```

it works fine as long as there are two nodes in my list but as soon as

I insert one element and do end(), I get an error which is normal because when I insert an element to my list I set it to the head of the list if the list is empty and tail stays as a nullptr.

So my solution was to check the list first

```
if (numberOfElements == 1 && tail == nullptr) {
    // Here I return the head of the list as there is no tail and head is pointing to the last element in the list. 
}
```

and then if there are more than 1 elements I return the tail.

I have tested this and it works fine but is this a good solution? If not can you please tell me why? Thank you

Comment: end() of containers returns in C++ usually an iterator thar points to "one after the end".

Comment: @manni66 but if I return head -> next I get **Segmentation fault: 11** however if i do tail -> next , it works fine

Comment: Your implementation is bad design. Don't name the function end. Why doesn't tail point to the same element as head does whenever there is only one element?

Comment: From the point of view of terminology your `end()` function should be called `rbegin()` - as in `std::vector` and others